Can there exist a definable "ultrafilter" on the ordinals?
Can there exist a model $\textit M$ of $\textit{ZF}$ (or $\textit{ZFC}$) that contains a definable nontrivial "ultrafilter" on $\sf Ord^{\textit M}$? By this I mean that there is some formula $\varphi(x, y, \overline p)$ and a proper $\textit M$-class $I$ (that is, $I$ is definable in $\textit M$), such that the following hold:

(intersection) $\textit M \models$ For every $i, j \in I$, there is some $k \in I$ such that $$\forall \alpha, (\varphi(i, \alpha, \overline p) \land \varphi(j, \alpha, \overline p) \iff \varphi(k, \alpha, \overline p))$$

(non-triviality) $\textit M \models$ For every ordinal $\beta$ there exists an $i \in I$ such that $\neg \varphi(i, \beta, \overline p)$.

(upwards closure) For every $C \subset D$, definable classes of ordinals in $\textit M$, if there is some $i \in I$ such that $$M \models C = \{\alpha \mid \varphi(i, \alpha, \overline p)\}$$ the there exists some $j \in I$ so that $$\textit M \models D = \{\alpha \mid \varphi(j, \alpha, \overline p)\}$$

(ultraness) For every $C$, a definable class of ordinals in $\textit M$, $\textit M \models$ There is some $i \in I$ such that $$C = \{ \alpha \mid \varphi(i, \alpha, \overline p)\}$$
or
$$C^c = \{ \alpha \mid \varphi(i, \alpha, \overline p)\}$$


In other words, we have a uniform definition in $\textit M$ of a filter over $\sf Ord^{\textit M}$ that contains every definable class or its complement. It is "ultra" on definable classes.
While this feels somewhat outrageous, the third property doesn't say much about what $\textit M$ actually satisfies, so I don't see a way to disprove this. In the other direction, global choice does not feel like enough to construct something like this. We would need some kind of second order global choice which I'm not sure how to define.

If $\varphi$ is $\Sigma_n$, then take $C$ to be the class of $\Sigma_{n+1}$-reflecting ordinals. Your hypothesis says that $C$ is $\Sigma_n$ from a parameter in $I$, but this is false, since it implies $\Sigma_{n+1}$ satisfaction over your model is $\Sigma_n$ from parameters.

To make the hypothesis harder to refute, why not ask whether there can be a definable basis for an ultrafilter in the sense of your question? So you'd remove the third bullet and replace the equalities in the fourth bullet with inclusions.

Even with Gabe's suggestion, there will be a trivial example. Just take any ultrafilter on $\omega$, and use it to define an ultrafilter on Ord, giving measure one to $\omega$. Since this isn't really what you want, you should require uniformity, that is, that every bounded set of ordinals has measure zero.

As Gabe pointed out in the comments, your requirements are too strong, since your properties will imply that the definability hierarchy collapses, as you require that every definable class of ordinals will be bounded by the complexity of $\varphi$.
If we adopt his suggestion to ask for a definable ultrafilter base, instead of the whole ultrafilter, then I as I pointed out in my comment, there will be a trivial example. Just take any ultrafilter on $\omega$ (or on any $\kappa$), and regard it as an ultrafilter on $\text{Ord}$ by making it concentrate on $\omega$. We can list out the continuum many subsets of $\omega$ in that ultrafilter as a filter base for an ultrafilter on $\text{Ord}$, and this will indeed generate a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\text{Ord}$.
So it seems natural to me to want to add the uniform requirement, requiring that the complement of any bounded set of ordinals is in the ultrafilter.
In this case, let me prove that it is impossible with V=HOD, or more generally, where $I$ is a class of ordinals.
Theorem. There is no uniformly definable ultrafilter base for a nonprincipal uniform ultrafilter on $\text{Ord}$, indexed by ordinals.
Proof. Suppose that we have a definable class $U\subseteq \text{Ord}\times\text{Ord}$ whose sections $U_i$ generate a uniform nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\text{Ord}$.
Define a class $X\subseteq\text{Ord}$ as follows. At stage $\alpha$, we will have specified $X$ up to some point, and we look at $U_\alpha$ above that point. Since by uniformity $U_\alpha$ must have points above that point, we add one of them to $X$ and then promise to omit one of them from $X$. And then continue to $\alpha+1$ and so forth. This produces a definable class $X$ of ordinals, which neither contains nor omits any section $U_\alpha$. So those sections are not an ultrafilter base. $\Box$
Update. As Farmer Schlutzenberg points out in the comments, one can improve the argument to avoid the assumption that $I$ is a set of ordinals. This fully answers the modified form of the question.
Theorem. In no model of ZF is there is a definable class $U\subseteq I\times\text{Ord}$ whose sections $U_i$ form a filter base for a nonprincipal uniform ultrafilter on $\text{Ord}$.
Proof. We define a class $X\subseteq\text{Ord}$ in stages. At stage $\alpha$, consider all the sections $U_i$ for $i\in I\cap V_\alpha$. We will have specified $X$ up to some ordinal. Since the filter base is uniform, we know every section is unbounded in $\text{Ord}$. So we can add a new big block $[\eta,\zeta)$ of ordinals, which contains an ordinal from every single $U_i$ for $i\in I\cap V_\alpha$. And then above that we can omit a block $[\eta',\zeta')$ that contains an element from every $U_i$ for $i\in I\cap V_\alpha$. Then proceed to stage $\alpha+1$. The result is a class of ordinals $X$ that neither contains nor omits any section $U_i$, and so the filter will not decide $X$, contrary to assumption. $\Box$

You can do a slight variant of this which works in general. At a given ordinal stage $\alpha$, say we have determined $X\upharpoonright\eta_\alpha$ where $\eta_\alpha\in\mathrm{Ord}$. To define $X\upharpoonright\eta_{\alpha+1}$, we will choose some $\xi_\alpha>\eta_\alpha$, and then choose $\eta_{\alpha+1}>\xi_\alpha$, and put $[\eta_\alpha,\xi_\alpha)\subseteq X$ and $[\xi_\alpha,\eta_{\alpha+1})\subseteq\mathrm{Ord}\setminus X$...

For $i\in I$ let $U_i={\gamma\in\mathrm{Ord}\bigm|\varphi(i,\gamma,\bar{p})}$. Now just choose $\xi_\alpha$ to be the least ordinal $\xi>\eta_\alpha$  such that  for every $i\in I\cap V_\alpha$, there is $\beta\in[\eta_\alpha,\xi)\cap U_i$, and then choose $\eta_{\alpha+1}$ to be the least $\eta>\xi_\alpha$ such that for every $i\in I\cap V_\alpha$, there is $\beta\in[\xi_\alpha,\eta)\cap U_i$. (And choice is irrelevant; ZF works.)

Ah, that's very nice. So this rules it out entirely for ZF models.

I have now updated my answer to include this improved form of the argument.

Okay, great! [adding some characters to reach minimum comment length...]

As pointed out by Gabe Goldberg (in the comments) such a $U$ cannot be definable, and as shown by Joel Hamkins' answer, $U$ cannot even have a definable base.
However, if instead of insisting that the ultrafilter $U$ has a definable filter base, we insist that $U$ is an "$M$-ultrafilter", then assuming that $M$ satisfies V=HOD, there is such a uniform ultrafilter. Here we say that $U$ is an $M$-ultrafilter if for every parameterically $M$-definable family $\langle X_\alpha:\alpha<\mathrm{Ord}^{M} \rangle$ of subsets of $\mathrm{Ord}^{M}$, we have $\{\alpha: X_\alpha \in U\}\in U$.

To see the construction of the desired nonprincipal uniform $M$-ultrafilter $U$ on the Boolean algebra of the parametrically definable subsets of $\mathrm{Ord}^M$ (where $M$ is a model of ZF in which V=HOD holds), see the second proof of Theorem 3.1 in this paper of mine.

By the way, the condition of being an $M$-ultrafilter is equivalent to: for each $n\in\omega$, the collection $U_n$ of members of $U$ that are $\Sigma_n$-definable is $M$-definable, i.e., there is a parametric formula $\psi
_{n}(\alpha ,\beta )$ such that $X\in U_{n}$ iff $$\exists \alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}^{M}~~~
X=\{\beta \in \mathrm{Ord}^{M}:M\models \psi _{n}(\alpha
,\beta )\}.$$
ADDENDUM. One might wonder how much completeness can one expect from a nonprincipal uniform $M$-ultrafilter as above.  It is easy to see that the $M$-ultrafilter condition guarantees that $U$ is $\aleph_{0}^{M}$-complete. However, as shown in Corollary 4.2 of the aforementioned paper of mine, one cannot even arrange $U$ to satisfy $\aleph_{1}^{M}$-completeness. In other words, the ultrapower of $M$ modulo a nonprincipal uniform $M$-ultrafilter $U$ (as above) always results in an elementary extension of $M$ that has new "natural numbers".
It is also noteworthy that one can use the main result of this joint paper of mine with Joel Hamkins to show the weaker result that $U$ is never $\mathrm{Ord}^M$-complete (a free preprint can be found here).
